# Error importing numpy in Google co lab using Android

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import numpy in Google co lab using Android but I am getting error shown in attached snap
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael S. allready mentioned in the comments, `Import` needs to be lowercase:

```py
import numpy as np
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write the "I" in lowercase. Like that `import numpy as np`